# DSLCalendarView reload

Tags: ios, iphone

I am using `DSLCalendarView` for displaying schedules. When month is changed, `didChangeToVisibleMonth` gets called. I am updating the data on this event. But I want the calendar to reload at this event too.
Is it possible to refresh/reload the `DSLCalendarView` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In DSLCalendarView.m, you will add the tag value for two view. below add the tag value code. just change in the file.

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
if (self != nil) {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(reloadCalendar:)
                                                 name:@"reloadCalendar"
                                               object:nil];

    [self commonInit];
}

return self;}

-(void)reloadCalendar{
    [self commonInit];
}

- (void)commonInit {
[[self viewWithTag:508] removeFromSuperview];
[[self viewWithTag:509] removeFromSuperview];
self.monthSelectorView.tag=508;
self.monthContainerView.tag=509;
}

- (void)didTapMonthBack:(id)sender {
NSDateComponents *newMonth = self.visibleMonth;
newMonth.month--;
[self commonInit];
[self setVisibleMonth:newMonth animated:YES]; } 

- (void)didTapMonthForward:(id)sender {
NSDateComponents *newMonth = self.visibleMonth;
newMonth.month++;
[self commonInit];
[self setVisibleMonth:newMonth animated:YES];}
```

if we will click the forward or back button in the calendar after that reload the calendar.

In view controller just a notification call method if we change the event call at the time method would call.

```
- (void)calendarView:(DSLCalendarView *)calendarView didChangeToVisibleMonth:(NSDateComponents *)month {

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]postNotificationName:@"reloadCalendar" object:self];
NSLog(@"Now showing %@", month);
```

}

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks.

Comment: Your always Welcome @Nitish

Answer (score 0):

I saw the library dont have any trick to do that, unfortunately dont have reload method :(. May be some work around solve the problem in your case.